# Sorting using a Repeater with pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination, repeater, code-behind

I have a repeater and I'm using pagination.  It works, but it does funny stuff with my sorting.  First of all, if I press the Sort button, my pagination control shows up twice.  Secondly, it paginates based on the default sort order.  Any ideas what might be wrong?

```
    protected void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show_Data();
    }

    public void Show_Data()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBRConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string srtOrder = cboSortBy.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select [ACCT_LIST].*, [ACCT_GRP_LIST].ACCT_GRP from [ACCT_LIST] LEFT JOIN [ACCT_GRP_LIST] on [ACCT_GRP_LIST].ACCT_GRP_PK = [ACCT_LIST].ACCT_GRP_FK ORDER BY " + srtOrder + "", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "TAcctList");

        //Pagination code so only a set number of records loads at a time.
        //  Done to speed up the loading, since this list gets really long.
        PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
        pds.DataSource = ds.Tables["TAcctList"].DefaultView;
        pds.AllowPaging = true;
        pds.PageSize = 20;

        int currentPage;

        if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
        {
            currentPage = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);
        }
        else
        {
            currentPage = 1;
        }

        pds.CurrentPageIndex = currentPage - 1;
        Label1.Text = "Page " + currentPage + " of " + pds.PageCount;

        if (!pds.IsFirstPage)
        {
            MenuItem itemMessage = NavMenu.FindItem("First");
            itemMessage.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=1";
        }

        AcctRepeater.DataSource = pds;
        AcctRepeater.DataBind();

        CreatePagingControl(pds.PageCount, pds.CurrentPageIndex);
        // End of Pagination code

        con.Close();
    }
```

And on the ASP.Net side, the button control looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="150"><asp:DropDownList ID="cboSortBy" runat="server" Width="120">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="StatusText">Benefit Type</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="PRIORITY_RANK">Priority Rank</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="ACTIVE_FLG">Active Flag</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>
    <td width="180"><asp:Button ID="btnSort" runat="server" 
        Text="Sort" Width="121px" onclick="btnSort_Click" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The pagination piece is new, but before it was added the sort functionality worked fine.  And now the pagination piece works fine but the sort piece went wonky.  I can't figure out which part of the pagination piece threw it out of whack.

Comment: I think the controls show up twice because I'm not doing a postback?  Not sure about the sorting issue, though.

Comment: OK, I think part of the problem is that the form is posting back, and the combo box holding the sort value gets reset to the default.  The link that my pagination creates looks like: http://localhost:50361/AdminForms/frmManageBenefitType.aspx?page=3.  So, I'm guessing when you click that it does a full postback which is resetting the sorting combo.  Anyone know how to combat that?  I guess I need to somehow carry the combo selected value forward.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ds.Tables["TAcctList"].DefaultView.Sort = "PRIORITY_RANK ASC";
```

Comment: The point is, it goes back to the default.  Hard-coding a sort order isn't going to help me, I need to get it to recognize the sort order when it refreshes.

Comment: Dont hardcode it. Get it from your dropdown list. I didnt think I had to get that specific. Sorry. The point is, set it in the above manner.